# Parallelizing command line tool by wrapping it in a bash script with gnu semaphore

Tags: bash, semaphore, gnu-parallel

I had to do an evaluation of a command line tool on a fairly big benchmark that consists of 50000 files.
Unfortunately, the tool was not parallelised and it took too long to run it sequentially on a benchmark of this size.
 I read some posts about gnu parallel (or gnu semaphore), but I could not find a good example that illustrates how one could combine the results of multiple background processes that are spawned by gnu semaphore.

The unwrapped tool requires one file as input parameter, and I had to figure out a way to gather all results that are yielded by running the tool multiple times in parallel. 
Furthermore, I did not want to lose any results in case of a crash. 
Whenever the script is cancelled, it should not re-process any file that has already been processed before.

For ensuring that the background process `worker` has enough work to do, the script below passes multiple files to the `worker` at once.
The bash script works quite well for my use case.

If somebody has a similar problem, I would like to share the script with you.
One can adapt the script to another use case by modifying the `worker` function and by modifying the variables `$JOBS` and `$WPSIZE`. 
I would be very happy if you could provide me some feedback on how to make the script more efficient.

Thanks a lot,
  Julian

```
#!/bin/bash

# make variables available in function started by
# gnu semaphore
export FINALRES="result.log"
export RESFIFO="/tmp/res.fifo"
export FILFIFO="/tmp/fil.fifo"
export FILELIST="/tmp/flist"
export WPSIZE=5
export JOBS=4

PUTFPID=""
WRITPID=""

# find input files fo process
find . -name "*.txt" > ${FILELIST}

# setup fifos and files
[ ! -e "${FINALRES}" ] && touch "${FINALRES}"
[ ! -e "${RESFIFO}" ] && mkfifo "${RESFIFO}"
[ ! -e "${FILFIFO}" ] && mkfifo "${FILFIFO}"

FILES=$(diff ${FINALRES} ${FILELIST} | grep '>' | cut -d '>' -f2 | tr -d ' ')
exec 4<> ${RESFIFO}
exec 5<> ${FILFIFO}

trap cleanup EXIT TERM

function cleanup() {
  # write results that have been obainted so far
  echo "cleanup"
  [ -n "${PUTFPID}" ] && (kill -9 ${PUTFPID} 2>&1) > /dev/null
  [ -n "${WRITPID}" ] && (kill -9 ${WRITPID} 2>&1) > /dev/null
  rm -f "${RESFIFO}"
  rm -f "${FILFIFO}"
  rm -f "${LOCKFILE}"
}

# this function takes always #WPSIZE (or less) files from the fifo
function readf() {
  local cnt=0
  while read -r -t 2 line; do
    echo "$line"
    [ -z "${files}" ] && { files=${line}; let cnt=${cnt}+1; continue; }
    let cnt=${cnt}+1
    [ ${cnt} -eq ${WPSIZE} ] && break
  done <& 5
}

# this function is called by gnu semaphore and executed in the background
function worker () {
  for fil in "${@}"; do
    # do something ...
    echo "result" > "${RESFIFO}"
  done
  exit 0
}

# this function is used (at the end) to write the comutation results to a file
function writeresult() {
  while read -r line; do
    [ "${line}" = "quit" ] && break
    echo "${line}" >> ${FINALRES}
  done < ${RESFIFO}
}

# this simple helper puts all input files into a fifo
function putf() {
  for fil in $FILES; do
    echo "${fil}" > "${FILFIFO}"
  done
}

# make function worker known to gnu semaphore
export -f worker
# put file into fifo
putf &
PUTFPID=$!
writeresult &
WRITPID=$!

while true; do
  ARGS=$(readf)
  [ -z "${ARGS}" ] && break
  # used word spitting on purpose here (call worker with multiple params)
  sem --bg --jobs "${JOBS}" worker ${ARGS}
done

sem --wait

echo "quit" > ${RESFIFO}
wait

echo "all jobs are finished"
exit 0
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thanks, I changed the script according to the spellcheck.net sanity checks except for the word splitting in line `sem --bg --jobs "${JOBS}" worker ${ARGS}` which I did on purpose ;-).

Comment: You could put `>> "${FINALRES}"` outside the loop containing it so you don't have to seek and append each and every result individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appending to a FIFO in parallel is generally a bad idea: You really need to know a lot about how this version of the OS buffers FIFOs for that to be safe. This example shows why:

```
#!/bin/bash

size=3000

myfifo=/tmp/myfifo$$
mkfifo $myfifo

printone() {
  a=$( perl -e 'print ((shift)x'$size')' $1 )
  # Print a single string
  echo $a >> $myfifo
}
printone a &
printone b &
printone c &
printone d &

# Wait a little to get the printones started
sleep .1

cat $myfifo | perl -ne 'for(split//,$_){
  if($_ eq $l) {
    $c++
  } else {
    /\n/ and next;
    print $l,1+$c," "; $l=$_; $c=0;
  }
}'
echo
```

With `size=10` you will always get:

```
1 a10 b10 c10
```

Which means that from the FIFO was read 10 a's followed by 10 b's followed by 10 c's. I.e. no mixing.

But change it to `size=100000` and you get something like:

```
1 d65536 b65536 c100000 d34256 b34256 a100000 d208
```

65K d's read, then 65K b's, then 100k c's, then 34K d's, 32K b's, then 100k a's, and finally 208 d's. I.e. the four outputs were mixed together. Very non-good.

For that reason I will advice against appending to the same FIFO in parallel: There is a risk of race condition, and it can often be avoided.

In your case it seems you simply want to `# do something ...` to each of the 50000 files, and that is dead simple:

```
do_something() {
  # do something ...
  echo do something to $1
  echo result of $1 is foo
}
export -f do_something
find . -name "*.txt" | parallel do_something > results
```

Here GNU Parallel helps you by making sure stdout and stderr do not mix for each of the jobs.

To avoid reprocessing in event of a crash/cancel, use `--joblog` and `--resume`.

Comment: Thanks a lot -- I will add locking to the script above to make it thread-safe.

Comment: Before doing that consider going through GNU Parallel's tutorial: It may save you a lot of time. man parallel_tutorial

Comment: Thanks Ole. I have changed the script according to your suggestions and the gnu parallel documentation. I made it available on https://gist.github.com/julianthome/161e6734c36611fcf03c91c9f76ebd5a